# I want to output the result of "kubectl get pod" excluding the key using LabelSelector of kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am learning Kubernetes Label Selector at the URL below.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/

#### Set-based requirement

> Set-based label requirements allow filtering keys according to a set of values. Three kinds of operators are supported: in, notin and exists (only the key identifier). For example:

```
! partition
```

> The fourth(This) example selects all resources without a label with key partition; no values ​​are checked.

My assumption is that if I specify "!test", all pods will be output,
I think that nothing is output when "!app" is specified.

I want to exclude the key and output as in the example described here, but the expected result was not obtained.

```
My @ Pc: ~ / Understanding-K8s / chap04 $ kubectl get pod -l! app
My@Pc:~/Understanding-K8s/chap04$ kubectl get pod -l !app
-bash: !app: event not found
My@Pc:~/Understanding-K8s/chap04$ kubectl get pod -l "!app"
-bash: !app: event not found
My@Pc:~/Understanding-K8s/chap04$ kubectl get pod -l "!test"
-bash: !test: event not found
My@Pc:~/Understanding-K8s/chap04$ kubectl get pod -l !test
-bash: !test: event not found
```

The result of executing the --show-labels command is as follows.

```
My @ Pc: ~ / Understanding-K8s / chap04 $ kubectl get pod --show-labels
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
nginx-pod-a   1/1     Running   0          89m   app=photo-view,env=stage
nginx-pod-b   1/1     Running   0          89m   app=imagetrain,env=test
nginx-pod-c   1/1     Running   0          89m   app=prediction,env=test
nginx-pod-d   1/1     Running   0          89m   app=photo-view,env=stage
nginx-pod-e   1/1     Running   0          89m   app=imagetrain,env=stage
nginx-pod-f   1/1     Running   0          89m   app=photo-view,env=prod
```

How can I exclude the intended keys such as app and env?

---

tyzbit has given me the answer, and I have tried.
I couldn't describe the result well in the comment, so I will add it here.

```
My@Pc:~/Understanding-K8s/chap04$ kubectl get pod -l '!app'
No resources found in default namespace.
My@Pc:~/Understanding-K8s/chap04$ kubectl get pod -l '!test'
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-pod-a   1/1     Running   0          162m
nginx-pod-b   1/1     Running   0          162m
nginx-pod-c   1/1     Running   0          162m
nginx-pod-d   1/1     Running   0          162m
nginx-pod-e   1/1     Running   0          162m
nginx-pod-f   1/1     Running   0          162m
```

---

Girdhar Singh Rathore teaches me AWK and jsonpath.

(Maybe, I've written the wrong format...)

AWK

```
My@Pc:~$ kubectl get pods --show-labels | awk  '$6 !~/app/ {print ;}'
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS

My@Pc:~$ kubectl get pods --show-labels | awk  '$6 !~/test/ {print ;}'
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
nginx-pod-a   1/1     Running   0          18m   app=photo-view,env=stage
nginx-pod-d   1/1     Running   0          18m   app=photo-view,env=stage
nginx-pod-e   1/1     Running   0          18m   app=imagetrain,env=stage
nginx-pod-f   1/1     Running   0          18m   app=photo-view,env=prod
```

jsonpath

```
My@Pc:~$ kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]} {.metadata.name} {.metadata.labels} {"\n"} {end}' | awk '$2 !~/app/ {print $1}'

My@Pc:~$ kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]} {.metadata.name} {.metadata.labels} {"\n"} {end}' | awk '$2 !~/test/ {print $1}'
nginx-pod-a
nginx-pod-d
nginx-pod-e
nginx-pod-f
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` is getting interpreted by your shell, use a single quote to prevent this.  The correct syntax is:

`kubectl get pods -l '!app'`

Comment: Tyzbit
Thank you for the answer! You save my time!
:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk`

```
kubectl get pods --show-labels | awk  '$6 !~/app/ {print ;}'
```

or `-o jsonpath`

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]} {.metadata.name} {.metadata.labels} {"\n"} {end}' | awk '$2 !~/app/ {print $1}'
```

or selector

```
kubectl get pods -l '!app'
```

Comment: Girdhar Singh Rathore
Thank you! I have tried it.
AWK is difficult for me now, but I added this log later.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use json output and print only label(s) which you want to output.

```
kubectl get no -o json | jq -r ".items[] | .metadata.labels.\"beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type\""
n2-highmem-2
n2-highmem-2
n2-highmem-2
```